# Check values in column(s) if all are the same

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I'm creating a check for a column.

**Goal:** I have a column called currency which I need to check if they are all the same for each Bank (Column A). If there are other currency then it will prompt me.

**Additional goal:** I would also like to include in the checking the one in column E (Currency (Bank Charge)) to make sure that all currencies for that bank are the same.

**Problem:** I already have a working code using scripting.dictionary, however, I have some trouble clearing the dictionary for the first loop / currencies for the first Bank. I tried to clear the dictionary before it proceeds to another bank. But it is not working.

Below is the screenshot of what I would like to check:

[image]

Below is the current code that I have:

```
Sub CurrencyTestCheck()

Dim wksSource As Worksheet: Set wksSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test1")

Dim i As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim strBankName As String

Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lastRow = wksSource.Cells(wksSource.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row 

For i = 2 To lastRow

If Len(wksSource.Cells(i, 1).Value) > 0 Then 'If a new bank starts

        If Len(strBankName) > 0 Then

                For Each k In d.Keys

                    strCheck = k
                    countCurrency = d(k)

                    msg = msg & strCheck & " - " & countCurrency & vbNewLine
                    x = x + 1

                Next k

                If x > 1 Then

                    MsgBox "There are different currencies for bank " & strBankName & vbNewLine & _
                    vbNewLine & msg, vbCritical, "Warning"

                Else

                    MsgBox "Currencies are all the same for " & strBankName, vbInformation, "Same currencies"

                End If

                d.RemoveAll

        End If


strBankName = wksSource.Cells(i, 1).Value

End If

    'Currency for each Bank

    tmp = Trim(wksSource.Cells(i, 3).Value)
    If Len(tmp) > 0 Then d(tmp) = d(tmp) + 1

Next i

If Len(strBankName) > 0 Then

    For Each k In d.Keys

        strCheck = k
        countCurrency = d(k)

        msg = msg & strCheck & " - " & countCurrency & vbNewLine
        x = x + 1

    Next k

    If x > 1 Then

        MsgBox "There are different currencies for bank " & strBankName & vbNewLine & _
        vbNewLine & msg, vbCritical, "Warning"

    Else

        MsgBox "Currencies are all the same for " & strBankName, vbInformation, "Same currencies"

    End If

End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

*Previous values are still in the dictionary (USD - 3 and AUD - 2)*

Appreciate if you also have another suggestion to do the checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have forgotten to reset your currency discrepancy counter `x`.
Set it to `x = 0` after the first bank's loop.

i.e.

```
...
...

    'Currency for each Bank

    tmp = Trim(wksSource.Cells(i, 3).Value)
    If Len(tmp) > 0 Then d(tmp) = d(tmp) + 1

Next i

' Add these two lines:
x = 0
msg = ""

If Len(strBankName) > 0 Then

    For Each k In d.Keys

        strCheck = k

...
...
```

And like TinMan said, also reset the `msg` so the previous bank's results don't leak into your the next bank.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the correct timing but the key point here is resetting your variables before proceeding to looping the next bank.

Comment: Indeed, it's the x that I missed to reset. I've tried to add the suggested answer and it worked. Thanks a lot!